# VSCode C++ Compilation Error (JSON files)

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, compilation

While compiling a cpp file on a remote ssh session on VSCode using g++, I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cezIH.png)

As can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q81lS.png), the asterisk isn't recognized for some reason, and the terminal tries to find a file literally named ***.cpp**.

Here are my json files:

**launch.json file:**

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json file:**

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
                "${fileDirname}/*.o",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: `"${fileDirname}/*.o",` is probably not wanted.

Comment: I included that for a specific problem I ran into since this is all for my uni course and we're sometimes given .o files we have to include in our compilation but I don't think it affects compilation in this case